# Android edittext - settextmethod cursor issue

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I am trying to settext in an EditText...But after setText is done, the cursor remains at the start of text.how can i move it to the end of the text?

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Best Regards,
Rony

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
EditText inputField;
Editable etext = inputField.getText();
int position = etext.length();
inputField.setSelection(position);
```

Answer (score 10):

Use `append(CharSequence text)`. This will also update the position of the cursor. [See Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence))

Answer (score 3):

Try `append("Hello");` instead of `setText()`