# Place cursor at the end of text in EditText

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext, keylistener

I am changing the value of an `EditText` on `keyListener`.

But when I change the text the cursor is moving to the beginning of the `EditText`.
I need the cursor to be at the end of the text.

How to move the cursor to the end of the text in a `EditText`.

Comment: I came across the same issue. But what I asked myself better is why this is happening, so that I could resolve the issue before instead of having to move the caret myself.

Comment: @kaneda I totally agree, however it would have been helpful if you had added the actual solution.

Comment: @Zainodis It was just a thought. Like I said I came across the same issue, which does not necessarily means that I've found the solution. In my case I had the issue with the `EditText`s as items of a `ListView`. As for experimentation, I made some changes on the `ListView` source code itself, which is a rather complex beast, and tested on the emulator. It was related to focus control management made by the component. So of course it's not a solution I could give to help our friend. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android edittext - settextmethod cursor issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141776/android-edittext-settextmethod-cursor-issue)

Comment: This does not work inside `OnFocusChanged` callback. The solution there is to put setSelection inside a runnable and run it on main thread. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32156989/4514796

Answer (score 1538):

Try this:

**UPDATE:**

**Kotlin:**

```
editText.setSelection(editText.length())//placing cursor at the end of the text
```

**Java:**

```
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```

Comment: This doesnt work in my case.  The setSelection() method seems to have no effect.  My EditText view contains ImageSpans.  Is there some other kind of workaround?

Comment: @marqss, I had the same issue and worked perfectly for me.  I was using EditText on a Dialog and pre-populating text from the main screen.  When that happens the cursor was staying at the beginning and not at the end but after I tried your suggestion everything is just fine, the way I wanted.  Thank you for posting this.

Comment: @toobsco42, try adding the line et.setSelection(et.getText().length());, whenever you change the text, like you may change the text on clicking a button. That's because the length of the EditText gets changed.

Comment: Hey @Mullay, I am now handling it by overriding the `onSelectionChanged()` method of an `EditText` class:

`public void onSelectionChanged(int start, int end) {

    CharSequence text = getText();
    if (text != null) {
        if (start != text.length() || end != text.length()) {
            setSelection(text.length(), text.length());
            return;
        }
    }

    super.onSelectionChanged(start, end);
}`

Comment: You may have to use et.post( new Runnable({... et.setSel... to get in the queue. This is because android waits to do some layout stuff until a better time by posting so if you try to setSelection before the system is finished it will undo your work.

Comment: It works here,thanks for your answer.But you should do like this:   editText.setText(s);
                    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length()); //after setText

Comment: Method name was not chosen wisely! not intuitive!

Answer (score 244):

There is a function called append for ediitext which appends the string value to current edittext value and places the cursor at the end of the value.
You can have the string value as the current ediitext value itself and call append();

```
myedittext.append("current_this_edittext_string");
```

Comment: If you already have text in your EditText, just write `myedittext.append("");`

Comment: @ymerdrengene just applying `myedittext.append("");` didn't worked for me!

Comment: This is perfect because it simply replaces the line of code I had. Was using edittextfield.setText and just swapped it for append. Very simple.

Comment: Depends on the usage if that works or not. For me it didn't. Using `Selection` is correct way of achieving that IMO.

Answer (score 166):

**Kotlin**:

set the cursor to the **starting position**:

```
val editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext_id) as EditText
editText.setSelection(0)
```

set the cursor to the **end of the EditText**:

```
val editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext_id) as EditText
editText.setSelection(editText.text.length)
```

Below Code is to place the cursor **after the second character:**

```
val editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext_id) as EditText
editText.setSelection(2)
```

**JAVA**:

set the cursor to the **starting position**:

```
 EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_id);
 editText.setSelection(0);
```

set the cursor to the **end of the EditText**:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_id);
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```

Below Code is to place the cursor **after the second character:**

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_id);
editText.setSelection(2);
```

Comment: Could replace `findViewById(R.id.edittext_id) as EditText` with `findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_id)` or just avoid the casting if using `API 26+`

Answer (score 138):

If you called `setText` before and the new text didn't get layout phase call `setSelection` in a separate runnable fired by `View.post(Runnable)` (repost from [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/0cZPTCOzyDs) topic).

So, for me this code works:

```
editText.setText("text");
editText.post(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
         }
});
```

Edit 05/16/2019: Right now I'm using Kotlin extension for that:

```
fun EditText.placeCursorToEnd() {
    this.setSelection(this.text.length)
}
```

and then - editText.placeCursorToEnd().

Comment: Thanks this really worked for me.  I was trying to call setSelection but it won't work.  In my case, I was trying to set a fixed prefix to edit text, and so after setting prefix, I needed  to set the cursor to end of prefix so that user can enter data after the prefix.  Since I was doing setSelection in constructor of a TextWatcher, may be thats why it did not work.  But your solution worked great!

Comment: I am using this post method in my MultiAutoCompleteTextView's Clickablespan method and it works.....I want the cursor to move at the end once the delete icon in the text span is clicked...It works in all the latest android mobiles...but in old versions it takes some time after the first click...all my other items does'nt become clickable...any clue??

Comment: I don't know why, but this is the only one that works for me! My edit text has a focus / text changed listener and is wrapped in a TextInputLayout. One of those things is messing it up.

Answer (score 44):

You could also place the cursor at the end of the text in the `EditText` view like this:

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textview);
int textLength = et.getText().length();
et.setSelection(textLength, textLength);
```

Answer (score 31):

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 28):

In my case I created the following **Kotlin ext. function**, may be useful to someone:

```
private fun EditText.focus(){
    requestFocus()
    setSelection(length())
}
```

Then use as follows:

```
mEditText.focus()
```

Comment: tnx. request focus was great.

Answer (score 23):

This is another possible solution:

```
et.append("");
```

Just try this solution if it doesn't work for any reason:

```
et.setSelection(et.getText().length());
```

Answer (score 15):

```
/**
 * Set cursor to end of text in edittext when user clicks Next on Keyboard.
 */
View.OnFocusChangeListener onFocusChangeListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
        if (b) {
            ((EditText) view).setSelection(((EditText) view).getText().length());
        }
    }
};

mEditFirstName.setOnFocusChangeListener(onFocusChangeListener); 
mEditLastName.setOnFocusChangeListener(onFocusChangeListener);
```

It work good for me!

Answer (score 14):

You should be able to achieve that with the help of `EditText's` method `setSelection()`, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#setSelection%28int%29)

Answer (score 14):

If your EditText is not clear:

```
editText.setText("");
editText.append("New text");
```

or

```
editText.setText(null);
editText.append("New text");
```

Answer (score 12):

i think this can achieve what you want.

```
 Editable etext = mSubjectTextEditor.getText();
 Selection.setSelection(etext, etext.length());
```

Comment: If my observations are correct, this spawns an instance of android.widget.TextView$IClipboardDataPasteEventImpl for each widget. I ended up with tons of them. Apparently they get eventually cleaned up, but seem to drive up the memory consumption. I had 12 instances of one dialog, it's only dominator (whats keeping it alive) being the above mentioned instance.

Comment: Placing that piece of code at appropriate position in code (where you are appending text directly to EText). Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The question is old and answered, but I think it may be useful to have this answer if you want to use the newly released DataBinding tools for Android, just set this in your XML :

```
<data>
    <variable name="stringValue" type="String"/>
</data>
...
<EditText
        ...
        android:text="@={stringValue}"
        android:selection="@{stringValue.length()}"
        ...
/>
```

Answer (score 7):

`editText.setSelection` is the magic here. Basically selection gives you place cursor at any position you want.

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```

This places cursor to end of EditText. Basically `editText.getText().length()` gives you text length. Then you use `setSelection` with length.

`editText.setSelection(0);`

It is for setting cursor at start position (0).

Answer (score 7):

Try This:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:cursorVisible="true"/>
```

In your code:

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length()); // Set cursor end point
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you want to select all text and just entering new text instead of old one, you can use

```
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
```

Answer (score 6):

This works

```
Editable etext = edittext.getText();
Selection.setSelection(etext,edittext.getText().toString().length());
```

Answer (score 6):

### For ViewModel, LiveData and Data binding

I needed this functionality for `EditText` with multiline support in my notes app. I wanted the cursor at the end of the text when the user navigates to the fragment that has note text.

The solution suggested by the [djleop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51789842/5925259) comes close. But the problem with this is that, if the user puts the cursor somewhere in the middle of the text for editing and starts typing, the cursor would jump to the end of text again. This happened because the `LiveData` would emit the new value and cursor would jump to the end of the text again resulting in user not able to edit the text somewhere in the middle.

To solve this, I use `MediatorLiveData` and assign it the length of `String` only once using a flag. This will cause the LiveData to read the value only once, that is, when the user navigates to the fragment. After that the user can place the cursor anywhere they want to edit the text there.

**ViewModel**

```
private var accessedPosition: Boolean = false

val cursorPosition = MediatorLiveData<Event<Int>>().apply {
    addSource(yourObject) { value ->
        if(!accessedPosition) {
            setValue(Event(yourObject.note.length))
            accessedPosition = true
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `yourObject` is another LiveData retrieved from the database that holds the String text that you are displaying in the `EditText`.

Then bind this `MediatorLiveData` to your EditText using binding adapter.

**XML**

Uses two-way data binding for displaying text as well as accepting the text input.

```
<!-- android:text must be placed before cursorPosition otherwise we'll get IndexOutOfBounds exception-->
<EditText
    android:text="@={viewModel.noteText}"
    cursorPosition="@{viewModel.cursorPosition}" />
```

**Binding Adapter**

```
@BindingAdapter("cursorPosition")
fun bindCursorPosition(editText: EditText, event: Event<Int>?) {
    event?.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let { editText.setSelection(it) }
}
```

**`Event` class**

The `Event` class here is like a [SingleLiveEvent](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) written by Jose Alcérreca from Google. I use it here to take care of screen rotation. Using the single `Event` will make sure that the cursor won't jump to the end of text when the user is editing the text somewhere in the middle and the screen rotates. It will maintain the same position when the screen rotates.

Here's the `Event` class:

```
open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {

    var hasBeenHandled = false
        private set // Allow external read but not write

    /**
     * Returns the content and prevents its use again.
     */
    fun getContentIfNotHandled(): T? {
        return if (hasBeenHandled) {
            null
        } else {
            hasBeenHandled = true
            content
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the content, even if it's already been handled.
     */
    fun peekContent(): T = content
}
```

This is the solution that works for me and provides good user experience. Hope it helps in your projects too.

Comment: This answer needs to be way up. Many Thanks

Answer (score 4):

All the other codes I've tested didn't work good due to the fact that the user could still place the caret/cursor wherever in the middle of the string (ex.: 12|3.00 - where | is the cursor). My solution always puts the cursor in the end of the string whenever the touch occurs on the EditText.

The ultimate solution is:

```
// For a EditText like:
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditTextAmount"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:hint="@string/amount"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/zero_value"
    android:inputType="text|numberDecimal"
    android:maxLength="13" />
```

Strings values:

```
@string/amount="0.00"
@string/zero_value="0.00"
```

In code:

```
// Create a Static boolean flag
private static boolean returnNext; 


// Set caret/cursor to the end on focus change
EditTextAmount.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View editText, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus) {
            ((EditText) editText).setSelection(((EditText) editText).getText().length());
        }
    }
});

// Create a touch listener and put caret to the end (no matter where the user touched in the middle of the string)
EditTextAmount.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View editText, MotionEvent event) {
        ((EditText) editText).onTouchEvent(event);
        ((EditText) editText).setSelection(((EditText) editText).getText().length());
        return true;
    }
});


// Implement a Currency Mask with addTextChangedListener
EditTextAmount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        String input = s.toString();
        String output = new String();
        String buffer = new String();
        String decimals = new String();
        String numbers = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(input.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")));

        if(returnNext) {
            returnNext = false;
            return;
        }

        returnNext = true;

        if (numbers.equals("0")) {
            output += "0.00";
        } else if (numbers.length() <= 2) {
            output += "0." + String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(numbers));
        } else if(numbers.length() >= 3) {
            decimals = numbers.substring(numbers.length() - 2);
            int commaCounter = 0;
            for(int i = numbers.length() - 3; i >= 0; i--) {
                if(commaCounter == 3) {
                    buffer += ",";
                    commaCounter = 0;
                }
                buffer += numbers.charAt(i);
                commaCounter++;
            }
            output = new StringBuilder(buffer).reverse().toString() + "." + decimals;
        }

        EditTextAmount.setText(output);
        EditTextAmount.setSelection(EditTextAmount.getText().length());
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        /*String input = s.toString();
        if(input.equals("0.0")) {
            EditTextAmount.setText("0.00");
            EditTextAmount.setSelection(EditTextAmount.getText().length());
            return;
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

FULLY WORKING SOLUTION!!!

kotlin, You need to use `post`

```
fun EditText.placeCursorToEnd() {
    this.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) {
            v.post { this.setSelection(text.length) }
        }
    }
    this.setOnClickListener {
        it.post { this.setSelection(text.length) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The .post did it for me. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

similar to @Anh Duy's answer, but it didnt work for me. i also needed the cursor to move to the end only when the user taps the edit text and still be able to select the position of the cursor afterwards, this is the only code that has worked for me

```
boolean textFocus = false; //define somewhere globally in the class

//in onFinishInflate() or somewhere
editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        editText.onTouchEvent(event);

        if(!textFocus) {
            editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
            textFocus = true;
        }

        return true;
    }
});

editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        textFocus = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This does the trick **safely**:

```
    editText.setText("");
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
        editText.append(text);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
etSSID.setSelection(etSSID.getText().length());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {
    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
        this.setSelection(this.getText().length());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {

    }
}
```

User this CustomEditText in your XML file, this will work. I have tested this and it is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to Place cursor at the end of text in EditText view

```
 EditText rename;
 String title = "title_goes_here";
 int counts = (int) title.length();
 rename.setSelection(counts);
 rename.setText(title);
```

Answer (score 2):

The above answers didnt worked for me. So i found out a new solution. This maybe helpful to someone. I have been using the latest version of Android Studio i.e 3.5 as per the present date. Maybe that might be the reason y the above answers didnt showed any effect.

CODE:

```
EditText available_seats = findViewById(R.id.available_seats);
Selection.setSelection(available_seats.getText(),available_seats.getText().length());
```

Here, the 1st argument is the Spannable text value that you want to playwith whereas the 2nd argument is the index value. Since, we want the cursor at the end of the text, we took getText().length() which returns the length of the text

Comment: My pleasure! Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

```
editText.accessibilityDelegate = object : View.AccessibilityDelegate() {
    override fun sendAccessibilityEvent(host: View?, eventType: Int) {
        super.sendAccessibilityEvent(host, eventType)
        if (eventType == TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_SELECTION_CHANGED) {
            editText.setSelection(editText.length())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below solution works even when there is default text is set and it does **NOT** blink cursor

```
 fun EditText.setCursorToEnd() {
    setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) {
            showKeyboard(this) // call your show keyboard function

            val text = this.text.toString()
            this.setText(text)
            this.setSelection(text.length) // Move the cursor to the end
        }
    }
}
```