# how to restore the edittext cursor position to end after requesting focus

Tags: android

When i request for a focus for an editext few times it is moving the cursor to beginning even if there is some text. How can we place the cursor in such a way that it will be immediately after the text that is already present in it??

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217378/place-cursor-at-the-end-of-text-in-edittext

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will set the cursor to the last position of the text:

```
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit Text has a property called append.I think the following line of code will also serve the purpose.

```
editText.append("");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Layout EditText give `android:ellipsize` property as end like this `android:ellipsize="end"`

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement, when user wants to edit and clicks on EditText, cursor should be at the end. I achieved the same using below:

```
edtDisplayName.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                edtDisplayName.setSelection(edtDisplayName.getText()
                        .length());

                edtDisplayName.requestFocus();

                //Open key board for user to edit
                Commons.showKeyBoard(OnBoardActivity.this, edtDisplayName);

                return true;

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Here's how I opened the key-board:

```
public static void showKeyBoard(Context context, View view) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(view, 0);
}
```