# setSelection in EditText's onFocusChange

Tags: android, focus

Normally, when the view is clicked, the text cursor is set near the place you clicked on.
I try to set it always to the end (past the last character), but it does nothing unless the action is delayed.
The following:

```
new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus) {
            EditText et = (EditText) v;
            et.setSelection(et.getText().length());
        }
    }
});
```

does not work. Delaying the `setSelection` part:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        et.setSelection(et.getText().length());
    }
}, 40);
```

makes it work, but is bad practice.

What better alternatives are there? `OnClickListener` and `OnTouchListener` (ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP both) don't help, either.

Comment: TIP: use `et.length()` instead

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need delay. we need to wait `setSelection` or else automatically called done and execute my `setSelection`.

```
new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus) {
            final EditText et = (EditText) v;
            et.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    et.setSelection(et.getText().length());
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `setSelection()` inside the `afterTextChanged()` of the `addTextChangedListener()`.

Comment: How do you mean? The intention is to move selection to end when the view is clicked. The text does not change in the meantime.