# Method setText() in EditText changing position of cursor

Tags: android, android-view

I wrote a library with a custom view that was extended from EditText.

I want when user calls setText()  cursor will stay at the same position

But by default EditText setText() moves cursor at the beggining

[image] -> **setText("1111")** ->
[image]

How can I fix it? Can I somehow override setText method (or other methods as bringPointToView() and so on)

**EDIT 1:**
It is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217378/place-cursor-at-the-end-of-text-in-edittext) question

Because I want to **override** a standard behaviour of cursor at the Edittext.

And **not** force user of lib to call **append() or setSelection()**

**EDIT 2:** 
My Solution

```
@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    super.setText(text, type);
    if (getText() != null) {
        Selection.setSelection(getText(), getText().length());
    }
}
```

Comment: While calling `setText()` call `editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());` too

Comment: As I said it is a library. I can not force user to call setSelection every time.
I want that it will be a default behaviour inside my custom Edittext for setText.

So the question is a little bit different

Comment: Question is a bit different and cannot be treated as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You should set text to "" and then append will move the cursor.

```
  YourEditText.setText("");
  YourEditText.append("youText");
```

Comment: This will only work if you're always editing the end of the EditText, otherwise editing text in the middle of the span will kick the cursor to the end on each entry.