# how to move edittext cursor to the end of getting focus?

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor, focus, move

I have multiple edit text fields. I want to move the cursor to the end when I tap on one of them. But the following code does not seem to work. It just places cursor where I tap.

```
    editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if(editText1.hasFocus()){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Got the focus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                editText1.setSelection(editText1.getText().length());

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: did you write this for all edit texts ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Place cursor at the end of text in EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217378/place-cursor-at-the-end-of-text-in-edittext)

Comment: yes its the same code on other edit text as well..